# What are the names in English for Alterando, Invertendo, Componendo and Dividendo?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

[image]

I am writing an article in English but don't want to use the Latin names. What are their English equivalent?

Comment: I have never seen these rules have a single-word English name.

Comment: I don't think any of these have names except possibly "invertendo" which could be called "taking the reciprocal of both sides of an equation".

Comment: There are no English names. People just refer to them in their Latin names. Helps that it's not widely taught in schools.

Comment: @Jonathan: And the next two would most likely be described as adding or subtracting $1$ and placing over a common denominator. The last is the only one that isn’t a completely trivial algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think those rules are called by their latin names, if one ever would give it names! Something like 'Corollaries of cross multiplication' could help.

Answer (score 1):

Alterando is "Alternendo".
And, componendo et dividendo is "componendo and dividendo".
Rest are all the same in English as in Latin.