# Complex number problem $i \tan (\theta)$ proof.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given $z = \cos (\theta) + i \sin (\theta)$, 
>   prove $\dfrac{z^{2}-1}{z^{2}+1} = i \tan(\theta)$

I know $|z|=1$ so its locus is a circle of radius $1$; and so $z^{2}$ is also on the circle but with argument $2\theta$; and $z^{2}+1$ has argument $\theta$ (isosceles triangle) so it lies on a line through the origin and $z$.

$z^{2}-1$, $z^{2}$, and $z^{2}-1$ all lie on a horizontal line $i \sin (\theta)$.

On the Argand diagram I can show $z^{2}+1$ and $z^{2}-1$ are perpendicular so the result follows.

Can anyone give an algebraic proof?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you mean $$z=\cos(\xi)+i\sin(\xi)$$?

Comment: I guess "Argand" rather than "Armand".

Comment: @badjohn: Argan (no *d*) was the first name of the main character in the famous "The Imaginary Invalid" by Molière. Armand is a little outmoded but still in use. ;-)

Comment: Joking?  I only know Argan as an ingredient in some fancy shampoos.  I know Armand as a name but, not as far as I know, an appropriate one here.  Are you saying that Armand may be appropriate?  Wolfram doesn't seem to know it: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArgandDiagram.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $z\ne0,$ with $|z|=1$

$$\dfrac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}=\dfrac{z-\dfrac1z}{z+\dfrac1z}$$

Now $\dfrac1z=\dfrac1{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$

Comment: That is elegant!

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For $z = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ you have
$$
 \frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1} = \frac{ \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta + 2i \cos\theta \sin \theta -1}{\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta + 2i \cos\theta \sin \theta +1 } \, .
$$
Now substitute $1 = \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta $ in both numerator and denominator, and collect terms:
$$
\frac{-2 \sin^2 \theta + 2 i \cos\theta \sin\theta}{2 \cos^2\theta + 2 i \cos\theta \sin\theta} = 
\frac{- \sin\theta + i \cos \theta}{\cos \theta + i \sin\theta} \cdot \frac{\sin\theta }{\cos\theta}  \, .
$$
Finally convince yourself that the first factor is equal to $i$, and
you are done.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}
=\frac{\dfrac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}}{\dfrac{z+\bar{z}}{2}}=
\frac{1}{i}\frac{z-\bar{z}}{z+\bar{z}}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{z-z^{-1}}{z+z^{-1}}=
\frac{1}{i}\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}$ reminds me of [Componendo and Dividendo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577231/what-are-the-names-in-english-for-alterando-invertendo-componendo-and-dividend)?

$\dfrac{z^2}1=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^2=\dfrac{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}{\cos\theta-i\sin\theta}$ as $\dfrac1{\cos\theta-i\sin\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$

Now apply Componendo and Dividendo